# Flags on back of robots in Portal 2 co-op

Tags: portal-2

I was just wondering if anyone knew what the flags on the back of the robots in co-op actually meant? I was playing as P-Body and had the flag on my back for the whole time as far as I could tell, but atlas definitely has a flag poll as well... any ideas?

Comment: Flags are items you can put on your robot yourself. Common examples include games from the Potato Sack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you select "Robot Enrichment" on the main menu, you can go to the Portal 2 Store, where you can purchase flair to make your robot look unique.

Flags are one of these items, and, specifically, those who bought the potato sack got flags with the logo of the game they played the most.

Comment: aw nice one, I must have put it on there in the daze of a 2am portal session and forgotten about it lol

Comment: Completing the single player also awards a flag.

Comment: @cruelcow it doesn't, it gives you a hat!

Comment: @ronan Forman: True, the flag I was thinking about you get for doing a high-five. http://theportalwiki.com/wiki/WCC_Flag